# Custom form "Data too long for column"

Tags: 8, forms, entities, database

I create a custom entity (pool) with a custom form.

In my custom form, i have a field (start_date)

```
$form['start_date'] = [
  '#type' => 'datetime',
  '#title' => t('Start Date'),
  '#default_value' => new DrupalDateTime()
];
```

When i want to save, i have the follow error :

"Data too long for column"

In the log, the value is : 2017-12-21 18:06:29 Europe/Paris 
Instead of 2017-12-21T17:06:29

What i'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal's DateTime field isn't ISO 8601 compliant, (doesn't save datetime values in the standard format you're expecting 2017-12-21T17:06:29).  You need to convert the value to UTC format for storage.  One approach is to initialize a date variable, convert it, and then pass as the value in your form field.

```
$currentDate = new DrupalDateTime();
if ($currentDate instanceOf DrupalDateTime && !$currentDate->hasErrors()) {
  $currentDate->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC');
  $db_friendly_value = $currentDate->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');
}

$form['start_date'] = [
  '#type' => 'datetime',
  '#title' => t('Start Date'),
  '#default_value' => $db_friendly_value
];
```

Specific notes about working with the DateTime API in D8 can be found in this [*"New DateTime API"* post](https://www.drupal.org/node/1834108).

This specific formatting issue was reported for the datetime module [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2821011).

Comment [6](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2821011#comment-11743073) shows the recommended approach to converting the date into the proper format for saving.

Answer (score 0):

So with your advices, i found a solution :

```
      public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        $form = parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
        $entity = $this->entity;

        $currentDate = new DrupalDateTime();
           $form['start_date'] = [
           '#type' => 'datetime',
           '#title' => t('Start Date'),
           '#default_value' => $currentDate
        ];
```

I add the function validateForm and setValueForElement

```
public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
{
$entity = $this->getEntity();
$currentDate = $form_state->getValues()['start_date'];
if ($currentDate instanceOf DrupalDateTime && !$currentDate->hasErrors()) {
  $currentDate->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone(DATETIME_STORAGE_TIMEZONE));
  $db_friendly_value = $currentDate->format(DATETIME_DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT);
}

$element[] = $db_friendly_value;

$element['#parents'] = ['start_date'];
$form_state->setValueForElement($element, $db_friendly_value);
$form_state->setTemporaryValue('entity_validated', TRUE);
```

}

And now it's ok in the db